# Is there a way to prevent an empty tab from showing up when using the --tab switch in a launcher for xfce4-terminal?

Tags: command-line, xfce, command, xfce4-terminal, launcher

Basically, I'd like to use a launcher to open a new tab with a program running in it when I already have a terminal open (obviously). To do this I use

```
xfce4-terminal --tab --drop-down -x
```

You'll notice I'm also using the

```
--drop-down
```

Which is essential to my ideal set up but am unsure if it matters to my question, but I included it just in case.

Anyway, what is bothering me is that when I have no terminal open at all and I use the above command/click launcher, what essentially amounts to a useless empty tab opens as well as the desired tab with the program running in it. Is there any way to prevent this empty tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple script like this can be used to prevent the empty tab:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=$(ps -e | grep -c xfce4-terminal)

if [ $c -gt 0 ]
    then
        xfce4-terminal --tab --drop-down -x $1
    else
        xfce4-terminal --drop-down -x $1
fi
```

Assuming the script is named `xfce4termtab`, the launcher command would be either

```
xfce4termtab program
```

or, with an argument

```
xfce4termtab 'program arg'
```

*Notes:*

- The script's permissions need to be set to make it executable.
- If the script isn't located in a directory on your PATH, you'll need to provide the full path to the script in the launcher command.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ment to check this solved a long time ago but life got in the way and well, I plum forgot. But seriously, this was EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks again!